# 16.04 won't connect to wifi on Acer Aspire with BCM43227

Tags: 16.04, drivers, wireless, broadcom

Decided to put an SSD in my old Acer Aspire laptop which was running Ubuntu 16.04 with no problems. Did a new install, couldn't see wifi networks and eventually went through System settings>Software & updates>Additional drivers and downloaded the Broadcom 802.11 linux driver. Now I can see wifi networks but can't connect to my network.

```
$ rfkill list details

0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no 
    Hard blocked: no

1: brcmwl-0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

2: acer-wireless: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

---

```
$ lspci  -knn | grep Net -A2 details

02:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Broadcom Corporation NetLink BCM57785 Gigabit Ethernet PCIe [14e4:16b5] (rev 10)
    Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] NetLink BCM57785 Gigabit Ethernet PCIe [1025:0504]
    Kernel driver in use: tg3
    Kernel modules: tg3

--
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM43227 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4358]
    Subsystem: Foxconn International, Inc. BCM43227 802.11b/g/n [105b:e040]
    Kernel driver in use: wl
```

Hope someone can help me get connected before I have to put my old HDD back....

Answer (score -1):

@user68186 is correct. Follow his link to that answer and follow the instructions carefully. You cited a new install - I can tell you from personal experience that another installation will require installing the Broadcom drivers again. I went from Ubuntu 16.04 LTS to Xubuntu 16.04 LTS (getting the results I wanted). I did have to install drivers for my Broadcom wireless device again as well. Your SSD addition is not the problem and so no need to return to the HDD. Just reinstall the drivers (I actually saved the answer to my documents folder and would recommend that as well.